# Metodo que no funciona

Tags: java

El problema es muy sencillo. Tengo el siguiente ejercicio:

> 1- Realizar un programa que solicite un texto por teclado y también solicite una palabra a buscar, 
>   introducidos los datos, el programa debe de mostrar cuántas veces aparace la palabra a buscar en el texto
>   que se ha introducido, sin importar si la palabra está en mayúscula o minúscula. Definir un método que 
>   devuelva el número de apariciones de la palabra a buscar.

Y aunque mi ojo poco experto no encuentra el error, mi programa no funciona par mas vueltas que le de. Si alguien mas experimentado pudiese echarme una manita, estaría muy agradecido.

```
package ejercicio1;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class CuentaPalabras {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int contador = 0;;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca un texto: ");
        String texto = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        ArrayList<String> textoAr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(texto.split(" ,.-_"))) ;
        System.out.println("Introduzca palabra a contar: ");
        String acontar = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        //System.out.println(textoAr);
        for(String palabra : textoAr) {
            contador += Contador(palabra, acontar);
        }
        System.out.println(contador);

    }

    public static int Contador(String palabra, String acontar) {
        if(palabra == acontar) {
            return 1;
        }else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Dame la clase contador tb que la vea, de todas maneras el metodo para contar deberia ir en la clase y en el main lo llamas

Comment: No he creado una class aparte, solo lo he creado fuera del main. Exigencias del profesor. Ese es mi código integro.

Comment: si llamas a un Contador com mayuscula salvo que exista algo asi que no recuerdo en java debe ser una clase aparte tp soy experto

Comment: Te recomiendo que aprendas a usar el debug. Así te puedes dar cuenta de como van las variables, y puedes ver por ejemplo lo que te comenta @riaven , donde estabas guardando toda la frase en la misma posición

Comment: Olvida el tolowercase usa compareToIgnoreCase asi te olvidas de si esta mayuscula minuscula

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tienes un problema al rellenar con `split()` el `array` `textoAr`, ya que te está guardando la frase completa, en una sola posición, eso quiere decir que cuanto quieres comparar, estás comparando una palabra con la frase entera, entonces por eso no coinciden:

```
 System.out.println(textoAr.get(0));
```

**Resultado**

> Hola soy una frase

De hecho, si imprimes el tamaño total del `array` `textAr`:

```
System.out.println(textoAr.size()); //Resultado 1, guarda en una sola posición la frase completa
```

> El resultado es `1`

Ahora bien, lo que pasa es que está fallando en separar los caracteres, ya que dentro de el `split` los símbolos deben de estar dentro de un corchete tal que así:

```
ArrayList<String> textoAr = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(texto.split("[ ,.-_]")));
```

De esta manera, habiendo un espacio o cualquiera de los demás signos que se encuentren dentro de los corchetes, separará la palabra del resto y la guardará en una posición diferente en el `array`.

---

Además no estás tomando cuántas son las veces que se repite la palabra correctamente, tienes un contador y no lo estas usando correctamente:

```
 //todos los métodos tienen que comenzar en minúscula
public static int contador(String palabra, String acontar) {
    if(palabra.equalsIgnoreCase(acontar)) { 
    //debe ser con equals o equalsIgnoreCase, ya que es texto
        return 1;
    }else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Véase [Expresiones regulares](https://jarroba.com/busqueda-de-patrones-expresiones-regulares/)

Comment: Sublime! Maravilloso! Gracias!

Comment: Cuando era una estudiante del primer año, tuve un ejercicio similar y me pasó lo mismo, errores de novata que cuestan tiempo y dolores de cabeza hahaha me alegra ayudar :)

Answer (score 5):

Podrías usar la siguiente solución:

```
public class CuentaPalabras {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca un texto: ");
        String texto = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("Introduzca palabra a contar: ");
        String acontar = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        contadorPalabras(texto, acontar);
    }

    public static void contadorPalabras(String palabra, String palabraBusqueda){
        // ELIMINA TODAS LAS VECES QUE SE REPITE LA PALABRA A CONTAR DEL TEXTO
        String palabraRestante = palabra.replace(palabraBusqueda, "");

        // SE OBTIENE LA LONGITUD DE TODAS LAS PALABRAS ELIMINADAS 
        // Y SE LE DIVIDE PARA LA LONGITUD DE LA PALABRA A CONTAR
        int longitudTotalPalabrasEncontradas = palabra.length() - palabraRestante.length();
        int numeroPalabras = longitudTotalPalabrasEncontradas / palabraBusqueda.length();
        System.out.println("Número de Palabras en el texto: " + numeroPalabras);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Prueba utilizando este metodo

```
public static int contarPalabras(String texto, String palabraAContar) {
    int apariciones = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (index < texto.length() && (index = texto.indexOf(palabraAContar, index)) >= 0) {
        apariciones++;
        index += palabraAContar.length(); 
    }
    return apariciones;
}
```

Este método funciona almacenando en la variable Index la posición en la que empieza a buscar, cuando encuentra la palabra suma uno a la variable apariones y establece el Index a la posición donde encontró la palabra más el tamaño de la palabra para que empieza a buscar la siguiente aparición partir de ahí

Comment: Por qué tu código resuelve la pregunta? Procura siempre explicar brevemente qué hace, cómo usarlo y por qué es mejor que el que se incluyó en la prgeunta.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un librería de Apache llamada Apache Commons Lang.Dicha librería posee una serie de métodos para trabajar con String que facilitan la vida en el día a día.
Para tu caso puedes utilizar [StringUtils.countMatches](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#countMatches(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)).

Dicho método se le pasa el texto donde buscar y la cadena a buscar y te devuelve el número de ocurrencias que tiene el texto.

Su código quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
            public static void main(String[] args) {
             Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
             System.out.println("Introduzca un texto: ");
             String texto = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
             System.out.println("Introduzca palabra a contar: ");
             String acontar = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();
             System.out.println("La palabra '"+acontar+"' se encuentra '"+StringUtils.countMatches(texto.toLowerCase(), acontar.toLowerCase())+"' veces en la frase introducida '"+texto+"'");
    }
```